# Why min function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have Symm(n) (symmetric matrix over $\mathbb R$), and we restrict the domain to $S^{n-1}$. Consider the function min: Sym(n)$\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, min(A):=minimum of $\left\Vert A\left(x\right)\right\Vert$ , x$\in S^{n-1}$, why this is continuous?.

Comment: What is the topology on F?

Comment: @Bungo sorry, now i think it makes sense

Comment: @Epet What norm are you assuming for $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$?

Comment: The operator norm, sup $\left\Vert A\left(x\right)\right\Vert , \left\Vert \left(x\right)\right\Vert =1$

Comment: Since A is diagonalizable, $\left\Vert A\right\Vert =\left|\lambda\right|$ where $\left|\lambda\right|$ is the eigenvalue of higher absolute value, and min(A)=$\left|\mu\right|$ where $\left|\mu\right|$ is the eigen value of lower absolute value.

Comment: Away from places where eigenvalues collide, you have continuity from the implicit function theorem (taking the equation $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$, giving $\lambda$ as an implicit function of $A$, which remains the lowest eigenvalue until the lowest eigenvalue hits the second lowest eigenvalue). There is some further technicality to get continuity through these "bad" points (the implicit function theorem no longer goes through in this circumstance).

Comment: @Ian Could the same idea be used with the minimum polynomial?

Comment: Sure, with the same caveats.

Comment: But in the case of minimum polynomial since A is diagonalizable there are no squares, but the degree of the minimum polynomial is variable between operators

Comment: Where that happens is exactly the "bad" points where the implicit function theorem is failing in the characteristic polynomial case. In particular, what I'm saying here is really all about the distinct eigenvalue case. You have to do more work to "fill the holes" made of matrices with non-distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you know that $\operatorname{Symm}(n)$ is a normed space in the operator norm (this is what your $\min(A)$ really is)?

For any normed space $(X, \|.\|)$, if we give $A$ the metric topology from the norm (using $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$), the function $f(x)  =\|.\|$from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous: This follows from the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) for norms:

$$\forall x,y \in X: |f(x) - f(y)| = \left|\|x\| - \|y\| \right| \le \|x-y\|$$

and shows we can $\delta = \epsilon$ uniformly.

Comment: The norm is continuous but min(A) is not a norm, since A(x)=0 if A is not injective. Maybe i misunderstood your answer

Comment: You defined $\min(A) = \min \{\|A(x)\|: x \in S^{n-1}\}$. The operatornorm is with $\max$, I suppose,IIRC. So it's not the norm, but bounded above by it. This will make no difference for continuity.